# Laravel - testing unique cookies creation in middlewares

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have a middleware that creates cookies for guest users and I'm struggling to test it. This is my middleware's `handle` function:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  $guestCookieKey = 'guest';

  if ($request->cookie($guestCookieKey)) {
    return $next($request);
  }

  return $next($request)->cookie($guestCookieKey, createGuestCookieId());
}
```

Testing this on the browser works perfectly: when request hasn't this cookie, it creates a new one. When it does have it, we just forward the request chain.

The problem is while testing this. Here's what I'm doing:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse;

class GuestCookieTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testItCreatesOnlyOneCookiePerResponse()
  {
    $firstResponse = $this->get('/');
    $secondResponse = $this->get('/');

    $this->assertEquals(
      $firstResponse->headers->getCookies()[0],
      $secondResponse->headers->getCookies()[0]
    );
  }
}
```

The error shows diffs between the two values:

```
Failed asserting that two objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie Object (
     'name' => 'guest'
-    'value' => 'eyJpdiI6IkttV2I2dldNelNkWXpyQXRWRUFlRUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQnBFYVlZNTNtYThjOWFxTTdLRXh4Zz09IiwibWFjIjoiZjY0NmEyNTMyMmM2MjJkNThmNmM5NWMxMDc2ZThmOTZjNDJhZTJjMmJhMGM0YTY0N2Q4NDg5YWEwNjI1ODEwZiJ9'
+    'value' => 'eyJpdiI6InRSMUVOSEZESm5xblwvOUU3aHQweGZ3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImhjU1lcL2pJUU1VbGxTN1BJQTdPWXBBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJmM2QyYjQ3NzU5NWU5Nzk2Yjg0Yzg4MmFlNGFmYTdkNThlNjZhNzVhMjE3YjUxODhlNzRkMjA0MWQzZmEyODM2In0='
     'domain' => null
     'expire' => 0
     'path' => '/'
```

It's like `$this->get` was not executed in the same environment (?), not preserving cookies set previously and creating unique calls and data for each call. This does make sense, but how would you test the creation of a guest cookie if no other with the same name is set?

Comment: You are indeed correct in assuming the requests run by the `get()` method are executed individually and each request will have its own life cycle, thus the cookies will be completely different for each request. That's because the `get()` method spins up a new Laravel kernel instance each time, much like Laravel does in `public/index.php`, but in this case you don't have the browser part of the equation which is responsible for persisting and keeping track of the cookies. So my suggestion is you try to use Selenium to evaluate your cookies across requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite of knowing about E2E test and tools, I had no idea there was something like [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk), which solved my problem.

After installing Laravel Dusk, it creates a `tests/Browser` folder.

I just had to create a test file like `GuestCookieTest.php` with the following content:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class GuestCookieTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    public function testItDoesNotOverwriteGuestCookieValue()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $firstCookieVal = $browser->visit('/')->cookie(config('guest'));
            $secondCookieVal = $browser->visit('/')->cookie(config('guest'));
            $this->assertEquals($firstCookieVal, $secondCookieVal);
        });
    }
}
```

Absolutely simple!